# What is meaning of $(2,3)$? where ( ) denotes a Principal Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

first instincts is that $(x,y)=(x) \cup (y) $ or $(x,y)=(x) \cap (y) $

but from class notes there is 1 line where putting in 2,3 $$(2,3)=3\mathbb{Z}+ 2\mathbb{Z} $$
***It comes from   extension fields, right?.* *Does it have a name?***

***Is there an alternate set notation for $(2,3)$?***

would it be $(2,3)=\{ 2k_1+3k_2:k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}\} $

---

First instincts is to say  $$(2,3)=3\mathbb{Z}+ 2\mathbb{Z}=5\mathbb{Z} $$
But $$ \begin{aligned} (2)=&\{ 0,\pm 2,\pm 4,\pm 6,\pm 8,\pm 10, \dots\}
            = \{ 2k: k \in \mathbb{Z} \}
 \\ 
 (3)=&\{0, \pm 3, \pm 6, \pm 9,\pm12,\pm15 \dots                 \} 
      =\{ 3k:k\in \mathbb{Z}                \}
\end{aligned}$$
and $$(2)+(3)=\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\pm 4,... \}=\mathbb{Z}=(1) \neq 5 $$

---

Found a [relatable question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126434/is-the-ideal-2-3-principal-in-mathbbqx) once writing it here, confirming that is is not (5)

I know it seems like a softball question but trying to get my foundations right.

Appreciate any constructive input, thanks.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that in some contexts in the study of algebra the notation $(a,b)$ can also be taken as shorthand for $\gcd(a,b)$, although that doesn't appear to be the usage in your question.  If you ever worry that your notation might be ambiguous to a reader, you may always remind them with words what the notation represents.

Comment: The parens do not connote a principal ideal on their own. If they surround a single element of the ring *that* denotes a principal ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the parentheses denote an ideal (not necessarily principal).  For instance, in the ring $\Bbb{Z}$,
$$
(3) = \{3k \mid k \in \Bbb{Z}\} = 3\Bbb{Z}.
$$
This ideal is *principal* since it's generated by a single element.  You can look at ideals generated by more than one element, though.  For instance, in $\Bbb{Z}$,
$$
(6, 15) = \{6i + 15j \mid i,j \in \Bbb{Z}\}.
$$
It turns out that in the ring $\Bbb{Z}$, **every ideal is principal** (but this is not the case for every ring).  In other words, we can find some $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that
$$
(6, 15) = n\Bbb{Z}.
$$
What is this $n$?  Consider the *greatest common divisor*:
$$
n = \gcd(6, 15) = 3.
$$
Notice that since $3$ divides $6$, we have $6 \in (3)$.  Analogously, $15 \in (3)$.  So we can conclude that $3$ divides any linear combination of $6$ and $15$, i.e., $(6, 15) \subseteq (3)$.

But what about the reverse inclusion?  Can we express $3$ as a linear combination of $6$ and $15$?  In other words, are there integers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$
6x + 15y = 3?
$$
[Yes!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)  One way is with $(x, y) = (-2, 1)$.  This shows that $3 \in (6, 15)$; therefore, $(3) \subseteq (6, 15)$.  Thus,
$$
(6, 15) = (3)
$$
and, generally, if $a, b \in \Bbb{Z}$,
$$
(a, b) = (d), 
\quad\text{where } d = \gcd(a, b).
$$

Comment: I never answered your specific question about $(2, 3)$, but I bet you can figure that one out.  *Hint:* it's an extreme case, as ideals go.

Answer (score 4):

In general, given a ring $R$ and a subset $S \subseteq R$, the ideal generated by $S$ is denoted $(S)$, is defined to be the set of finite $R$-linear combinations of elements of $S$, that is
$$(S) = \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n r_is_i : n \in \mathbb{N},\ r_i \in R,\ s_i \in S \right\}$$
When $S = \{ s_1, s_2, \dots, s_k \}$ is finite, we just write $(s_1, s_2, \dots, s_k)$ instead of $(\{s_1, s_2, \dots, s_k \})$.

So for example if $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $S = \{ 2, 3 \}$, then
$$(S) = (2,3) = \{ 2a+3b : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \mathbb{Z}$$
Such ideals need not be principal; in fact, principal ideals are precisely those of the form $(s)$, where $s \in R$. For example,
$$(2,X) = \{ 2a+bX : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$
is not a principal ideal of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed the set of linear combinations of 2 and 3, as you wrote: $(2,3)=\{ 2k_1+3k_2:k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}\} $   You can simplify that though,  as that's also known as any multiple of the gcd of 2 and 3, and since 2 and 3 are relatively prime, we get $(2,3)=(1)=\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_k)$ in a ring $R$ is used to denote the ideal generated by the elements $x_i\in R$. Linear algebraically this is the $R$-linear span of the elements $\{x_1, \dots, x_k\}$. Similarly, as a module, this denotes the direct sum $Rx_1\oplus R x_2\oplus \cdots \oplus Rx_k$